# google sheets email PDF and remove the content creator?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pdf-generation

I am using a script to build my report in google sheets, then mail it out. The mail function builds the pdf from the tab, names it, and sends it. It all works great, but I want to know is it possible to remove the "content creator: Google Sheets" when you look at get info (on Mac) on the PDF. I do not want the recipient to see it was made in google sheets.

```
function RunFunction() {
  makePDF(); //it calls myFunction(); at end of makePDF()
}

function mailPdf(shNum, shRng, pdfName, email, subject, htmlbody) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var shId = shNum ? ss.getSheets()[shNum].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');
var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
      + (shId ? ('&gid=' + shId) : ('&id=' + ssId))
      + (shRng ? ('&range=' + shRng) : '') // Modified to use the dynamic range
      + '&format=pdf'
      + '&size=letter'                      //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
      //+ '&portrait=false'               //true= Potrait / false= Landscape
      //+ '&scale=1.1'                      //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
      + '&top_margin=0.5'                 //All four margins set to 0.5 inches
      + '&bottom_margin=0.5'
      + '&left_margin=0.5'
      + '&right_margin=0.5'
      + '&gridlines=false'              //true/false
      //+ '&printnotes=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&pageorder=2'                  //1= Down, then over / 2= Over, then down
      //+ '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
      + '&vertical_alignment=TOP'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
      //+ '&printtitle=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&sheetnames=false'             //true/false
      //+ '&fzr=false'                    //true/false frozen rows
      //+ '&fzc=false'                    //true/false frozen cols
      //+ '&attachment=false'             //true/false

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments: blob, htmlBody: htmlbody
    }

    MailApp.sendEmail(
      // email + "," + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() // use this to email self and others
      email,                                              // use this to only email users requested
      subject + ' (' + pdfName + ')',
      'html content only',
      mailOptions
    );
  }
}

function myFunction() {

  var sheetNameToExport = "PDF"; // Replace this with the name of the sheet to export (e.g., "PDF")
  var rangeToExport = "A1:F300"; // Range to make pdf
  var pdfName = "Sheet PDF"; 
  var recipientEmail = "XXXXXXXX@gmail.com"; /
  var emailSubject = "PDF Subject line"; 
  var htmlBodyContent = "This is a test run<br><br> "; // Replace this with the HTML content of the email (can be plain text as well)

  // Find the index of the sheet by its name
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetIndex = sheets.findIndex(function (sheet) {
    return sheet.getName() === sheetNameToExport;
  });

  if (sheetIndex !== -1) {
    // Call the mailPdf function with the provided parameters
    mailPdf(sheetIndex, rangeToExport, pdfName, recipientEmail, emailSubject, htmlBodyContent);
  } else {
    Logger.log("Sheet not found: " + sheetNameToExport);
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to delete the creator of metadata of PDF data created by your script.

In this case, how about the following sample script? In this answer, in order to remove the value of "Creator" of metadata of PDF data, [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) is used.

#### Sample script:

In this modification, your function `mailPdf` is modified, and also, I added a new function `deleteCreator_` as follows.

```js
function deleteCreator_(blob) {
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  };
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(new Uint8Array(blob.getBytes()), { updateMetadata: true });
      pdfDoc.setCreator("");
      const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();
      const newBlob = Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, blob.getName());
      resolve(newBlob);
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

function mailPdf(shNum, shRng, pdfName, email, subject, htmlbody) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ssId = ss.getId();
  var shId = shNum ? ss.getSheets()[shNum].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = ss.getUrl().replace(/edit$/, '');
  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   //export as pdf
    + (shId ? ('&gid=' + shId) : ('&id=' + ssId))
    + (shRng ? ('&range=' + shRng) : '') // Modified to use the dynamic range
    + '&format=pdf'
    + '&size=letter'                      //A3/A4/A5/B4/B5/letter/tabloid/legal/statement/executive/folio
    //+ '&portrait=false'               //true= Potrait / false= Landscape
    //+ '&scale=1.1'                      //1= Normal 100% / 2= Fit to width / 3= Fit to height / 4= Fit to Page
    + '&top_margin=0.5'                 //All four margins set to 0.5 inches
    + '&bottom_margin=0.5'
    + '&left_margin=0.5'
    + '&right_margin=0.5'
    + '&gridlines=false'              //true/false
    //+ '&printnotes=false'             //true/false
    //+ '&pageorder=2'                  //1= Down, then over / 2= Over, then down
    //+ '&horizontal_alignment=CENTER'  //LEFT/CENTER/RIGHT
    + '&vertical_alignment=TOP'       //TOP/MIDDLE/BOTTOM
  //+ '&printtitle=false'             //true/false
  //+ '&sheetnames=false'             //true/false
  //+ '&fzr=false'                    //true/false frozen rows
  //+ '&fzc=false'                    //true/false frozen cols
  //+ '&attachment=false'             //true/false
  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
      'muteHttpExceptions': true
    }
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {

    // --- I modified the below script.
    deleteCreator_(blob)
      .then(b => {
        var mailOptions = { attachments: [b], htmlBody: htmlbody }
        MailApp.sendEmail(
          // email + "," + Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() // use this to email self and others
          email,                                              // use this to only email users requested
          subject + ' (' + pdfName + ')',
          'html content only',
          mailOptions
        );
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // ---

  }
}
```

- When your function `mailPdf` is run with the valid arguments, the metadata of "Creator" is removed from the PDF data created by `var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf')`. And, the PDF blob without "Creator" of metadata is returned.

#### Note:

- **Of course, in this case, you can also use the pdf-lib library by copying and pasting the script library retrieved from https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js in the script editor of Google Apps Script. In this case, the process cost for loading it can be reduced.**

#### References:

- [pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/)
- [setCreator of pdf-lib](https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument#setcreator)

Comment: Is it possible to change the meta data to something custom? Id love to put my company name on there instead of the "Google Sheets" If not I am happy to just delete it but if its just as easy to set my own custom meta data instead I would go that route.

Comment: @John Velella Thank you for replying. About `Is it possible to change the meta data to something custom? Id love to put my company name on there instead of the "Google Sheets" If not I am happy to just delete it but if its just as easy to set my own custom meta data instead I would go that route.`, in this case, please modify `pdfDoc.setCreator("");` to `pdfDoc.setCreator("### your company name ###");` and test it again.

Comment: @John Velella `pdfDoc.setCreator("");` can be seen in the function `deleteCreator_(blob)`.

Comment: @John Velella About `That worked great! Thank you.`, welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @John Velella I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my English. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around for any option to modify the properties the PDF will have once exported but I'm afraid this is not available in the Drive API as
[export links](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/files#exportLinks:%7E:text=the%20About%20resource.-,exportLinks,-map%20(key%3A%20string)) is a read-only object. You'll get the same behavior as opening the Spreadsheet, then click on **file** > **download** > **pdf**
Sorry I can't offer a workaround at the moment, but if you have the chance I can recommend opening a [Feature Request for the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/support#developer_product_feedback)  'cause it will definitely come handy having the chance to modify those values.